# Cannot borrow element as mutable more than once at a time for an array elements in Rust

Tags: rust

I have such code that can't be compiled:

```
fn my_cool_replace<T: Copy>(arr: &mut [T]) {
    swap(&mut arr[2], &mut arr[5]);
}

fn swap<T: Copy>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
    let c: T = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `arr[_]` as mutable more than once at a time
```

I want the function `my_cool_replace` to replace 2-th and 5-th elements in the given mutable slice of an array or a vector. Why do I have such error and what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap

Comment: Also possibly interesting: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html The introductory example in the link produces essentially the same error message as your example.

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you for the link. Although I would like to know more about the nature of the error occurred.

Comment: In your `my_cool_replace` function, you are passing an mutable reference to the array, `arr`. The full rust error message tells you more specifically that `&mut arr[2]` is the first borrow of the mutable reference, and that `&mut arr[5]` is the second. You can't have more than one. Even though you've got different indices, rust is looking at `arr` as a whole so both are borrows of the same immutable reference. @Pandemonium provided a way to write `swap` for array elements that avoids that issue.

Comment: @Fomalhaut read the rust book so

Comment: I hope you're aware that std already includes [`<[T]>::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html?highlight=reference%20and%20Borrowing#the-rules-of-references):

> Here are the rules for borrowing in Rust:
>
> First, any borrow must last for a scope no greater than that of the
> owner. Second, you may have one or the other of these two kinds of
> borrows, but not both at the same time:
>
> - one or more references (&T) to a resource,
> - exactly one mutable reference (&mut T).

Your `swap` function smells weird by accepting references as arguments. Instead, it could have been rewritten to accept a mutable reference to an array and the indices the user like to swap:

```rust
fn swap<T: Copy>(arr: &mut [T], p1: usize, p2: usize) {
    let tmp = arr[p1];
    arr[p1] = arr[p2];
    arr[p2] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This `clone()` is redundant (and also the trait bound) you have `Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

As already correctly stated, you can't do this in one swoop ─ but:

```
fn my_cool_replace<T: Copy>(arr: &mut [T]) {
    let mut tmp = arr[5];
    tmp = std::mem::replace(&mut arr[2], tmp);
    _ = std::mem::replace(&mut arr[5], tmp);
}
```